# Python pandas. Комбинирование данных

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Всем привет!
У меня есть исходный датафрейм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сгруппировать его так, чтобы напротив каждого имени было перечисление предметов (важно чтобы с пробелом), и появился новый столбец с их кол-вом, как здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался сделать через groupby и agg, но ничего дельного не вышло. Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Данные, код и желаемый результат в вопросе должны быть в воспроизводимом виде, а не скриншотами. Ваша попытка решения тоже должна быть отражена в вопросе. В противном случае ваш вопрос нарушает правила сайта и может быть закрыт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, что "ничего дельного" у вас не вышло. Вероятно, не сильно пытались...

```
df["Количество предметов"] = pd.NA
res = df.groupby("Имя").agg({"Предмет": lambda x: " ".join(x),
                             "Количество предметов": len})
```

res:

```
                                 Предмет  Количество предметов
Имя                                                           
Артем  Литература Агнглийский Математика                     3
Иван   Литература Агнглийский Математика                     3
Лиза               Литература Математика                     2
​
```

а лучше, наверное так, без `df["Количество предметов"] = pd.NA`, но с:

```
res = df.assign(newcol=pd.NA).groupby("Имя").agg({"Предмет": lambda x: " ".join(x),                             
                             "newcol": len}).rename(columns={"newcol":"Количество предметов"})
```

чтобы не вносить изменения в исходный датафрейм.

а еще лучше, чтоб покроче и без переимнований, так:

```
kwargs = {"Количество предметов" : pd.NA}
res = df.assign(**kwargs).groupby("Имя").agg({"Предмет": lambda x: " ".join(x),
                                              "Количество предметов": len})
```

Answer (score 3):

еще вариант:

```
df = (df.groupby('имя')['предмет'].agg([' '.join, 'count'])
      .set_axis(['предметы', 'кол-во'], axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно так:

```
df = df.pivot_table('Предмет', 'Имя',aggfunc={'Предмет': [('Предмет', lambda x: ' '.join(x)), ('Кол-во предметов', 'count')]})[['Предмет','Кол-во предметов']]
```

```
                                Предмет  Кол-во предметов
Имя                                                      
Артем  Литература Английский Математика                 3
Иван   Литература Английский Математика                 3
Лиза              Литература Математика                 2
```